# Why can't I initialize non-final instance variables in C++ or make variable-sized arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, for-loop

I have little to no knowledge of C++ and how to use arrays. That being said, what I'm trying to do is create a simple class for chemical elements which automatically decides the number of shells allotted to that element based on just its atomic number. Here's my sample code:

```
class Element {
   int n, i;
   int s = 1; 

   for (int i = 2; i < n; i += 8) {s += 1;}  

   int shell[s + 1];

   public: Element(int n) {this.n = n;}
};
```

That snippet of code is supposed to create an array called `int shell[s + 1]` which contains s-1 shells. I made it s-1 instead of s so I wouldn't constantly confuse myself by referring to shell #1 as shell[0] and so forth. Thus, shell[0] is unused. Or I could do it the other way around and actually use shell[0], but that's irrelevant. As you can see, `int s` is automatically set to 1 because all elements contain at least one shell. Then there's a for loop that adds shells based on `int n`. Finally, I declared the array `int shell[s + 1]`.

Ultimately, I got a multitude of errors. Most of them were nonsensical syntax errors, but apparently in C++ you're not allowed to initialize non-final instance variables. That doesn't make much sense to me, because I really need `int s` to begin at 1 for the for loop. It also tells me that I can't make variable-sized arrays, either. What do?

Comment: You can't put a for-loop outside of a function body. Besides that, C++ doesn't support variable length arrays. The size must be a compile-time constant. But you can use `std::vector<int>` and instantiate it with a runtime-determined size. I suggest you learn some basic C++ first. There are just too many problems with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `std::vector<int>` and initialize it in constructor:

```
class Element {
   int s, n;
   std::vector<int> shell;

   public: Element(int n) : s(1), n(n) {
       for (int i = 2; i < n; i += 8) {s += 1;}  
       shell.resize(s + 1);
   }
};
```

Comment: @SteveJessop: I thought that when initialization list is used, the members are initialized in the order they appear in initialization list regardless the order of their declarations within class.

Comment: Quite contrary; they are initialised in order of declaration in class *regardless* of the order in the initialiser list. Otherwise, there would be no way to generate one code for the destructor (as the objects need to be destroyed in reverse order of initialisation).

Comment: @Angew: Aaah, okay :) I'm not sure why I remembered it the opposite way, but this makes perfect sense :)

Comment: You forgot to let me know that I needed the vector header file, but other than that this works so thanks.